# Import-CSV Powershell, Exclude Records Containing String?

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I have a section of a script here where I am importing a CSV but trying to only select records where AppName does not contain "Security"

Here is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working; the records I am trying to omit still appear.

```
$file2 = import-csv -Path "$UpdatePath\$($todaydate).csv" | where {$_.AppName -notcontains "Security"} | Select-Object AppName
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: try `-notlike` instead of `-notcontains` also you can put a wildcard '*' before and after security.

Comment: check out `help about_comparison_operators` in powershell to get a full understanding of how the comparison operators work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file2 = import-csv -Path "$UpdatePath\$($todaydate).csv" | where {$_.AppName -notlike "*Security*"} | Select-Object AppName
```

`-notlike` will do this, but I also added asterisks which are a wildcard character in the *like* operators.

`-contains` is actually for arrays (think collections of values).

[about_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)